# how to add multiple tab support feature in my notepad application using java?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I made a notepad application using java swing and currently it has the following features in it, you can create a new file and save it to the desired location also you can open an existing file, edit it and save it on a new location or update the existing one.Now i want to add the feature that would support the multiple file editing/creating at the same time, just like in notepad++. I have not much idea about how could this be done, please tell me the way to do it.would multi threading help?

Comment: *"..would multi threading help?"*  Not really.  Seems the GUI needs a `JTabbedPane`.  You have worked that out, right?

Comment: You might start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, and i dont understand what you guys want to know, should i write whole stories about how i even did the typing of my code, every question i post is put on hold as unclear by one or the other guy, i seriously don't find any flaw in my question this time.I think from next time i will type big and long stories about how i got the idea, how i opened my IDE, how many times i pressed enter, backspace, etc etc, would it be fine guys?i guess then it wont be put on hold as unclear by geniuses like you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the jTabbedPane documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

With the tabbed pane you can use several components and manage them all without threading (only one tab is active at a time) it will just require some additional logic to determine which tab/text area you are currently viewing when the toolbar features are used.